# pagination when using Array.splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, pagination

I'm rendering a list of cards to my app. There are 13 in total. I need to show them 3 per page and then I have a button that can be clicked to move along to the next 3, so on and so forth until the end. I'm using the Array.splice method to show the cards. The parameters for the first page are 0 and 3 (`props.trucks.slice(0, 3)`). For the second page, it should be 3 and 6 (`props.trucks.slice(3, 6)`). Clicking the next page button should follow that pattern until cards are exhausted. How can I accomplish this??

### Update:

As of now, I'm almost there but I haven't figured out how to stop the function from continuing once I get to the end of the cards. The code in `splitJump` below will show the last card. Then, if I click next, it shows nothing and then if it I click it again, it shows that last card again.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    const [spliceParams, setSpliceParams] = useState({
        spliceStart: 0,
        spliceEnd: 3
    })

    const spliceJump = () => {
        if (spliceParams.spliceStart >= props.trucks.length) {
            setSpliceParams({
                spliceStart: props.trucks.length - 1,
                spliceEnd: spliceParams.spliceStart + 3
            })
        } else {
            setSpliceParams({
                spliceStart: spliceParams.spliceStart + 3,
                spliceEnd: spliceParams.spliceEnd + 3
            })
        }
    }

    const spliceReverse = () => {
        setSpliceParams({
            spliceStart: spliceParams.spliceStart - 3,
            spliceEnd: spliceParams.spliceEnd - 3
        })
    } 

    {!props.cuisineTypeMode && <div className="card-div">
                <div className="card-sub-div">
                    <div className="trucks-category-div">
                        <h3 className="trucks-category">Nearby Trucks</h3>
                        <p>View all</p>
                        <div className="category-pagination-arrows">
                            <div className="arrow-bg-div">
                                <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" onClick={spliceReverse}></i>
                            </div>
                            <div className="arrow-bg-div">
                                <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" onClick={spliceJump}></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="trucks-div">
                        {props.trucks && (props.trucks).slice(spliceParams.spliceStart, spliceParams.spliceEnd).map(truck => (
                            <Card className="truck-card" onClick={() => selectTruck(truck.id)}>
                            <CardActionArea>
                                <CardMedia
                                className="truck-img"
                                image={truck.image}
                                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                />
                                <i 
                                    className="like-icon" 
                                    class={filterThroughFavs(truck.id).length > 0 ? "fas fa-heart" : "far fa-heart"}
                                    onClick={filterThroughFavs(truck.id).length > 0 ? e => removeFromFavorites(e, truck.id) : e => addToFavs(e, truck.id)}
                                />
                                <CardContent>
                                <Typography className="truck-name" gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                    {truck.name}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography>
                                    {truck.avg_rating}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography className="cuisine-type" component="h3">{truck.cuisine_type}</Typography>
                                <Typography className="distance-plus-rating" component="h3">
                                    {truckDistance[truck.index]}
                                    {/* {console.log(`props.location: ${props.location}, truck.current_location: ${truck.current_location}, returns: ${getTruckDistance(props.location, truck.current_location)}`)}
                                    {console.log(getTruckDistance(props.location, truck.current_location))}   */}
                                </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                            </CardActionArea>
                        </Card>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>}
```

[image]

Comment: Maintain a start and end variable, increment/decrement by 3 on next/prev click and check for boundary conditions ( not less than 0, not mroe than max length of cards, etc), use the start and end variables in `.slice()`

Answer (score 1):

Sample code, You can enhance accordingly.

```
class Products {

  constructor() {
    this.state.currentIndex = 0;
    this.noOfElement = 3
  }
  onNext() {
    const currentIndex = Math.min(this.state.currentIndex + this.noOfElement, props.trucks.length)
    this.setState({
      currentIndex
    })
  }
  onPrev() {
    const currentIndex = Math.max(this.state.currentIndex - this.noOfElement, 0)
    this.setState({
      currentIndex
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (<div className="trucks-div">
      {props.trucks && (props.trucks).slice(this.state.currentIndex, this.state.currentIndex + this.noOfElement).map(truck => (
        <Card className="truck-card" onClick={() => selectTruck(truck.id)}>

        </Card>
      ))}
    </div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried your code. It didn't work for me. I don't think the noOfElement can be hard coded to 3 like you have it. Because the way, Array.slice works, the second parameter is the cut off point of the array and not the number of elements to show from the array, as I believe you are assuming.

Comment: oh yeah! typo.. just to avoid hard coding